# Sendmail catchall for sending messages

Tags: sendmail

I am trying to change my development environment so that any emails sent from my machine through sendmail are redirected to a single address.

I have seen several examples using FEATURE(`virtusertable') like this

```
@example.com          catch-all@delivery.host.name
```

but the problem is I want to catch EVERYTHING, not just @example.com, and redirect it to a single address on an external domain (gmail). Currently I have sendmail setup on CentOS 6.5.

So, for example, I want to catch an emails that could be sent to

```
user@exampleA.com
user@exampleB.com
user@exampleC.com
```

and redirect them to

```
dev@myActualServer.com
```

How do I set sendmail up to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use smart host to catch all outgoing messages (messages to non local mailboxes).

sendmail.mc

```
dnl Send all no local emails to local email address catch-all 
define(`SMART_HOST',`local:catch-all')
```

/etc/mail/aliases

```
# define catch-all alias
catch-all:  johndeveloper1, archive
```

If you want to send messages to an external account using smtp then use:

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`esmtp:johndoe1@example.net')
```

---

Use `LUSER_RELAY` to catch messages to non existing local mailboxes in local email domains.

Use `MAIl_HUB` to catch messages to all local email addresses in local email domains.

More complicated recipes allow to copy all envelope recipient addresses to email headers.

Comment: If I understand you correctly mightymouse is my local user account. In this sense since I want to send the emails to an external account, how would LUSER_RELAY/MAIL_HUB to accomplish that. For example, I want to send the emails to a gmail account.

Comment: A have appended one more variant to the answer - it will send to external server via SMTP (without SMTP AUTH).  Using gmail as destination may be risky due to incoming email limits imposed by gmail.

Comment: Looking at the limits for Gmail, I don't think I will ever hit them.